# scipy minimize with constraints

Tags: python, math, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

Let's suppose I have a matrix

```py
arr = array([[0.8, 0.2],[-0.1, 0.14]])
```

with a target function

```py
def matr_t(t):
    return array([[t[0], 0],[t[2]+complex(0,1)*t[3], t[1]]]

def target(t):
    arr2 = matr_t(t)
    ret = 0
    for i, v1 in enumerate(arr):
          for j, v2 in enumerate(v1):
               ret += abs(arr[i][j]-arr2[i][j])**2
    return ret
```

now I want to minimize this target function under the assumption that the `t[i]` are real numbers, and something like `t[0]+t[1]=1`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This constraint

```
t[0] + t[1] = 1
```

would be an equality (`type='eq'`) constraint, where you make a function that must equal zero:

```
def con(t):
    return t[0] + t[1] - 1
```

Then you make a `dict` of your constraint (list of dicts if more than one):

```
cons = {'type':'eq', 'fun': con}
```

I've never tried it, but I believe that to keep `t` real, you could use:

```
con_real(t):
    return np.sum(np.iscomplex(t))
```

And make your `cons` include both constraints:

```
cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun': con},
        {'type':'eq', 'fun': con_real}]
```

Then you feed `cons` into `minimize` as:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(func, x0, constraints=cons)
```

Comment: @user1943296 Not exactly sure how to implement that, if your input is complex, the output might be too.  The first constraint _might_ imply that `t.imag.sum()` is zero, since we're only comparing it to real 1, but my edit shows a more explicit constraint.

Comment: how to do that if I want `con` >0 , <0, >=0 or <=0 ,I find `type` only has two type `ineq` and `eq`

Comment: @wyx From the doc: "Equality constraint means that the constraint function result is to be zero whereas inequality means that it is to be non-negative. Note that COBYLA only supports inequality constraints". Your can always rewrite your eq/ineq constraint to express it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a custom constraint function, you can construct a `scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint` object and pass it as the constraint. Its construction asks for upper and lower bounds; also the vector of independent variables has to have the same length as the variable length passed to the objective function, so the constraint such as `t[0] + t[1] = 1` should be reformulated as the following (because `t` is length 4 as can be seen from its manipulation in `matr_t()`):

[image: constraint]

Also `minimize` optimizes over the real space, so the restriction of `t[i]` being real is already embedded into the algorithm. Then the complete code becomes:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

def matr_t(t):
    return np.array([[t[0], 0],[t[2]+complex(0,1)*t[3], t[1]]]

def target(t):
    arr2 = matr_t(t)
    ret = 0
    for i, v1 in enumerate(arr):
          for j, v2 in enumerate(v1):
               ret += abs(arr[i][j]-arr2[i][j])**2
    return ret

arr = np.array([[0.8, 0.2],[-0.1, 0.14]])
linear_constraint = LinearConstraint([[1, 1, 0, 0]], [1], [1])
result = minimize(target, x0=[0.5, 0.5, 0, 0], constraints=[linear_constraint])

x_opt = result.x            # array([ 0.83,  0.17, -0.1 , 0.])
minimum = result.fun        # 0.0418
```

---

For a more involved example, let's use a common problem in economics, [Cobb-Douglas utility maximization](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ewainwrig/Econ201/6500/mrs-notes.pdf) as an illustrative example. This is actually a constrained maximization problem but because `minimize` is a minimization function, it has to be coerced into a minimization problem (just negate the objective function). Also in order to pass the constraints as a `scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint` object, we have to write them to have lower and upper bounds. So the optimization problem is as follows:

[image: problem]

In this function, there are two variables `x` and `y`; the rest are all hyperparameters that have to be externally supplied (alpha, beta, `px`, `py` and `B`). Among them only alpha and beta are parameters of the objective function, so they must be passed to it through `args=` argument of `minimize` (`alphas` in the example below).

The optimization problem solves for `x` and `y` values where the objective function attains its minimum value given the constraint. They must be passed as a single object (`variables` in the function below) to the objective function. As mentioned before, we must pass an educated guess for these variables (`x` and `y` of the objective function) in order for the algorithm to converge.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

def obj_func(variables, hyperparams):
    x, y = variables
    alpha, beta = hyperparams
    return - x**alpha * y**beta

B, px, py, alphas = 30, 2, 5, [1/3, 2/3]
linear_constraint = LinearConstraint([[px, py], [1, 0], [0, 1]], [-np.inf, 0, 0], [B, np.inf, np.inf])
result = minimize(obj_func, x0=[1, 1], args=alphas, constraints=[linear_constraint])

x_opt, y_opt = result.x     # 4.9996, 4.000
optimum = result.fun        # 4.3088
```

`result.x` are the minimizers and `result.fun` is the local minimum.

<sup>Cobb-Douglas has a closed form solution where for the example input, the correct solution is `(x_opt, y_opt) = (5, 4)`. The result of `minimize` is not quite equal to that but since `minimize` is an iterative algorithm, this is as close as it got before it stopped.</sup>