# Scipy & Optimize: Minimize example, how to add constraints?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a dataset, and I'd like to find a mixed gaussian model by least square error method.

The code is like this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
kde = KernelDensity().fit(sample)

def gaussian_2d(x,y,meanx,meany,sigx,sigy,rho):
    # rho <= 1
    part1 = 1/(2*np.pi*sigx*sigy*sqrt(1-0.5**2))
    part2 = -1/2*(1-rho**2)
    part3 = (((x-meanx)/sigx)**2-2*rho*(x-meanx)*(y-meany)/(sigx*sigy)+((y-meany)/sigy)**2)
    return part1*exp(part2*part3)

def square_error(f1,f2, u1,v1,sigu1,sigv1,rho1, u2,v2,sigu2,sigv2,rho2, u3,v3,sigu3,sigv3,rho3):
    # 1. Generate Mixed Gaussian Model
    def gaussian1(x,y):
        return gaussian_2d(x,y,u1,v1,sigu1,sigv1,rho1)
    def gaussian2(x,y):
        return gaussian_2d(x,y,u2,v2,sigu2,sigv2,rho2)
    def gaussian3(x,y):
        return gaussian_2d(x,y,u3,v3,sigu3,sigv3,rho3)
    mixed_model = f1*gaussian1(x,y)+f2*gaussian2(x,y)+(1-f1-f2)*gaussian3(x,y)
    # 2. Calculate the sum of square error
    sum_error = 0
    for point in sample:
        error = (exp(mixed_model(point)) - exp(kde.score(point)))**2
        sum_error += error
    return sum_error

# How can I add constraints:
# f1+f2 <= 1
# rho1,2,3 <= 1
result = sp.optimize.minimize(square_error)
```

But I don't know how to add constrains in `minimize` method. The example in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize is very hard to understand.

UPDATE:
This is what I end up with,

```
result = sp.optimize.minimize(
    square_error,
    x0 = [0.2,0.5,
          1,1,1,1,0.3,
          1,1,1,1,0.3,
          1,1,1,1,0.3,],
    bounds = [(0., 1.),(0., 1.),
              (None, None),(None, None),(0., None),(0., None),(0., 1.),
              (None, None),(None, None),(0., None),(0., None),(0., 1.),
              (None, None),(None, None),(0., None),(0., None),(0., 1.),])
```

But it gives me `TypeError: square_error() takes exactly 17 arguments (1 given)`, what's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scipy minimize with constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075714/scipy-minimize-with-constraints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add only add bounds if the solver supports them, so only for `method='L-BFGS-B'`, `TNC` and `SLSQP`.

The bounds are passed via a sequence of `(min, max)` tuples whose length corresponds to the number of your parameters. An example for fitting with 3 parameters would be:

```
result = sp.optimize.minimize(
                        square_error,
                        method='L-BFGS-B',
                        bounds=[(0., 5.), (None, 1.e4), (None, None)])
```

Here, `None` corresponds to no bound.
I'm afraid that constraints on a combination of parameters such as `f1+f2 <= 1` in your example is not possible within the framework of `bounds` in `scipy.minimize`.

You can, however, simply return `np.inf` in your cost function if your bounds are violated. I'm not sure about the stability of this, though:

```
def square_error(f1,f2, other_args):
    if f1+f2 <= 1:
        return np.inf
    # rest of the cost function
```

Moreover, I'd suggest to use the python implementation of [multivariate Gaussians](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html#numpy.random.multivariate_normal) instead of creating them from scratch. That will speed up your fitting, help to avoid bugs and be more readable.

Comment: `I'm afraid that constraints on a combination of parameters such as f1+f2 <= 1 in your example is not possible.` This is not true. There are solvers especially for constrained optimization that support them.

Comment: Could you provide a link? I was referring to the solvers that are included in `scipy.minimize`.

Comment: Just have a look at the `constraints` keyword. OP is trying to define constraints rather than simple bounds.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'm afraid I misunderstood the OP. I'll update my answer accordingly. Meanwhile, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075714/scipy-minimize-with-constraints for a great answer.

Comment: For the `np.random.multivariate_normal`, I need the exact probability density value, and the module seems only provide `sample`?

Comment: So, in the end, its a mix of `constraints` and `boundry` settings?

Comment: Hi, I've update my code. It gives me `square_error() takes exactly 17 arguments (1 given)`, I don't know what's wrong, can you help me with this?