# optimize a function with two bounded matrices as inputs

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to optimise a loss function which takes two inputs "m, d" as inputs. Both of these are (32, 32, 1) matrices. I am not able to figure out how to bound/constrain their values between 0 and 1. "m, d" are filters that I apply to some input being fed into a trained ML model.

I have looked at these documentations

https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/index.html#id54
(See Box-Bounds; hyperlink in Chapter Contents)
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

[scipy minimize with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075714/scipy-minimize-with-constraints)

```py
def lossfunction(MD):
    m = MD[:, :, 0]
    d = MD[:, :, 1]
    x = data[np.argwhere(label != 6)]
    xt = np.multiply((1 - m), x) + np.multiply(m, d)  # Todo: Apply Filter
    num_examples = xt.shape[0]
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    totalloss = 0
    for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
        batchx, batchy = xt[offset:offset + BATCH_SIZE], (np.ones(BATCH_SIZE) * targetlabel)
        loss = sess.run(loss_operation, feed_dict={x: batchx, y: batchy, prob: 0.8})
        totalloss = totalloss + loss
    finalloss = totalloss + lam * np.linalg.norm(m, 1)
    return finalloss


optimize.minimize(lossfunction, np.zeros((32, 32, 2)), bounds=((0, 1), (0, 1)))
```

I get this error message: ValueError: length of x0 != length of bounds

I understand that the bounds and inputs should be of the same dimensions.
Is there a convenient way of inputting the bounds?

Comment: According to the docs, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html, `x0` the initial value is supposed to have a shape `(n,)` - that is, a 1d array.  You provide a 3d array.  I think that will be flattened to 1d before being sent to the `lossfunction`.  And the `bounds` is supposed to be a `(min, max)` pair for each element of `x` (32*32*2 such tuples!).  You can replicate a tuple with `[(0,1)]*3` syntax.

Comment: Yes the above worked