# Using Xgboost Model as an Objective Function for an Optimizer

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy, xgboost, gekko

I am trying to solve a budget allocation problem, where budget needs to be allocated across 20 different marketing products. I have an xgboost model that takes in the budget (and some other variables which are pre-computed) to predict the resultant sales. I need to choose n (n<=20) products out of 20 in such a way that the overall sales is maximized.

I am trying to allocate budget in proportions like 10% of budget to product1, 5% to product2 etc. There is a function that calculates what should be the maximum budget proportion to be allocated for each of these products.

I tried using Gekko but the Gekko datatype is not supported by xgboost and hence throws errors. I cant really create combinations of all possible allocations and search within that space due to time and memory constraints.

I tried using scipy but it does not respect the bounds or even constraints for that matter. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Adding the code that I used below

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective_function(allocations, budget=budget):
    individual_predictions = [predict_results(allocations[i], i)
for i in range(num_products)]
    total_prediction = -sum(individual_predictions)
    if np.sum(allocations)!=1:
        loss=1e+9
    elif np.sum(allocations>0)!=7:
        loss=1e+9
    elif check_bounds(allocations, bounds)==False:
        loss=1e+9
    else:
        loss=total_prediction/budget
    return loss

num_products=len(preferred_list)

def total_allocations_constraint(allocations):
    return np.sum(allocations) - 1

def total_selections_constraint(allocations):
    return np.sum(allocations>0) - 7

def nonnegativity_constraint(allocations):
    return np.sum(allocations<0)

constraints = (
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': total_selections_constraint},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': total_allocations_constraint},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': nonnegativity_constraint},
)

initial_allocations = [0 for i in preferred_list]

bounds = [(0, get_upper_bound(index_lookup.get(i))) for i in range(num_products)]

from datetime import datetime
t0=datetime.now()
print("Started at", t0)
result = minimize(objective_function, 
                  initial_allocations, 
                  method='trust-constr', 
                  bounds=bounds,
                  constraints=constraints)

optimized_allocations = result.x

print("Completed at", datetime.now())
print("Optimized Allocations:", optimized_allocations)
```

Comment: Should work with Scipy. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20076951/4611565) answer help ?

Comment: @manu190466 tried that. The optimizer is not respecting the bounds or constraints even after setting method as trust constraints

Comment: Did you use the `method='SLSQP'` like in the example given in the Scipy documentation ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Tried all the methods that do not require a jacobian. None of it worked @manu190466

Comment: Could you try with a simple (fake) function, similar to your xgboost model, to see if it is a Scipy bug or a misuse of it. Then post your code to get more help.

Comment: @manu190466, I tried with a simple linear model and scipy does not respect bounds or constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Gekko does not currently support xgboost or other tree-based methods. Because the back-end solvers use gradient descent based methods, the decision functions of models need to be diffentiable and rewritable with Gekko variables. So far, Gaussian process regression, support vector regression, linear regression, and neural networks have been integrated into Gekko: https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ml.html. I suggest you remodel your problem with one of those if possible, or use other heuristic-based solvers to solve your optimization problem.